# Get ERROR: sling-2.0.0-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, api, terminal, version

I get the error "ERROR: sling-2.0.0-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. " when trying to install this SLING package.

I run the following command:

$ sudo -H pip3 install http://www.jbox.dk/sling/sling-2.0.0-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl
ERROR: sling-2.0.0-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

This is my python version: 
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3

I check various posts but still don't know how to get rid of it. Please help me, thank you!

Comment: The wheel is for Linux x86_64 only. Are you trying to install on OS X? That won't work. The bottom of the install page has instructions for OS X. If you are on linux - what is the output of 'uname -a' ? https://github.com/google/sling/blob/master/doc/guide/install.md

Comment: $ uname -a
Darwin sekifudzukis-MacBook-Pro.local 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Sun Jun  2 20:26:31 PDT 2019; root:xnu-3789.73.50~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: The above comment is what I go on Mac terminal

Answer (score 0):

These install instructions will not work on a Mac - only on linux. See the bottom of the install page https://github.com/google/sling/blob/master/doc/guide/install.md

Sling install guide says "We currently do not support OSX, but you can check out issue #189 for help on building on OSX."

https://github.com/google/sling/issues/189

Your milage may vary. Those tips are two years old, and things may have changed so they may not work. It may be simplest to run a linux virtual machine on your Mac, into which you install python sling.